# Select rows satisfying condition on two variables jointly in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two dataset, `big_table` and `small_table`

```
    big_table = structure(list(FXW = structure(c(7L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 
1L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 
1L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
5L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 
1L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 2L), .Label = c("AA", 
"AF", "AG", "AH", "AI", "BG", "EH", "FF"), class = "factor"), 
    CP = c("CAD/AOA", "CHF/AUD", "CAD/ATS", "USD/CDF", "JPY/CDF", 
    "EUR/AUD", "JPY/CNY", "EUR/AOA", "CHF/CDF", "CAD/CDF", "USD/CNY", 
    "EUR/AUD", "JPY/AUD", "USD/CDF", "JPY/ATS", "JPY/CDF", "CAD/CNY", 
    "GBP/ATS", "CHF/AOA", "GBP/AUD", "USD/CNY", "JPY/CDF", "CHF/AOA", 
    "GBP/ATS", "EUR/AUD", "GBP/BDT", "EUR/AOA", "GBP/ATS", "JPY/CNY", 
    "CAD/ATS", "CAD/CNY", "CHF/CDF", "EUR/CNY", "JPY/BDT", "GBP/BDT", 
    "EUR/AUD", "CAD/CDF", "CAD/ATS", "GBP/ATS", "EUR/AUD", "JPY/ATS", 
    "GBP/BDT", "EUR/ATS", "CAD/CNY", "CHF/AUD", "CHF/CDF", "CAD/ATS", 
    "CAD/CDF", "CAD/CNY", "JPY/CDF", "JPY/BDT", "USD/BDT", "EUR/CNY", 
    "CHF/CDF", "GBP/CNY", "CHF/CNY", "CHF/CDF", "CHF/AUD", "CAD/AUD", 
    "GBP/ATS", "CHF/BDT", "JPY/AUD", "CHF/BDT", "CAD/BDT", "CHF/AUD", 
    "CAD/ATS", "CAD/CNY", "CAD/ATS", "JPY/BDT", "GBP/CNY", "GBP/AUD", 
    "USD/AOA", "USD/AOA", "GBP/AOA", "GBP/AOA", "EUR/CNY", "CAD/CNY", 
    "JPY/CDF", "CHF/CNY", "CAD/BDT", "USD/CNY", "CHF/AOA", "GBP/AUD", 
    "USD/AUD", "CHF/BDT", "JPY/ATS", "JPY/ATS", "GBP/BDT", "JPY/AOA", 
    "JPY/AUD", "GBP/CDF", "CHF/CDF", "USD/ATS", "CHF/CNY", "CHF/BDT", 
    "CAD/ATS", "EUR/AUD", "CHF/CDF", "JPY/BDT", "GBP/AUD")), .Names = c("FXW", 
"CP"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))



        small_table = structure(list(SWH = structure(c(8L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 
6L, 6L, 4L), .Label = c("AA", "AF", "AG", "AH", "AI", "BG", "EH", 
"FF"), class = "factor"), SCP = structure(c(5L, 23L, 19L, 36L, 
12L, 28L, 14L, 7L, 10L, 21L), .Label = c("CAD/AOA", "CAD/ATS", 
"CAD/AUD", "CAD/BDT", "CAD/CDF", "CAD/CNY", "CHF/AOA", "CHF/ATS", 
"CHF/AUD", "CHF/BDT", "CHF/CDF", "CHF/CNY", "EUR/AOA", "EUR/ATS", 
"EUR/AUD", "EUR/BDT", "EUR/CDF", "EUR/CNY", "GBP/AOA", "GBP/ATS", 
"GBP/AUD", "GBP/BDT", "GBP/CDF", "GBP/CNY", "JPY/AOA", "JPY/ATS", 
"JPY/AUD", "JPY/BDT", "JPY/CDF", "JPY/CNY", "USD/AOA", "USD/ATS", 
"USD/AUD", "USD/BDT", "USD/CDF", "USD/CNY"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("SWH", 
"SCP"), row.names = c(256L, 238L, 19L, 179L, 83L, 243L, 265L, 
186L, 189L, 128L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to use `dplyr` to select the subset of rows of `big_table` for which the pairs `(big_table$FXW, big_table$CP)` are in `(small_table$SWH, small_table$SCP)` *jointly*.

Comment: I guess you can use a `semi_join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do an `inner_join`

```
inner_join(big_table, small_table, by = c(FXW = "SWH", CP = "SCP"))
```

Comment: @docendodiscimus  WIth the example OP provided, both give the same result.  May be he/she should have given a better example.  Also, to make it same, we can wrap it with `unique` or `distnct`

Comment: @docendodiscimus  This can be wrapped with `unique` to make it same (if there is another example)

Comment: It's not clear to me what the differences are. Sorry for the involuntary bad example. If it is any help, Sotos's answer does exactly what I want.

Comment: @user189035  I thought your tag was dplyr.  Anyway docendodiscimus I haven't tested it as the example was not adequate.  I guess you might be right

Comment: on the given example, I get 'Warning message:
In inner_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y) :
  joining character vector and factor, coercing into character vector' ;(

Comment: Yes, I confirm, `inner_join` is what I wanted. Sorry for the ambiguous question!

Comment: @user189035  That is just a friendly warning as there is a mix of class.

Answer (score 3):

Another way that translates your description ("`(big_table$FXW, big_table$CP) are in (small_table$SWH, small_table$SCP)`") would be

```
big_table[do.call(paste, big_table) %in% do.call(paste, small_table),]

#or to specify the columns you want to compare,

big_table[do.call(paste, big_table[,c('FXWAREHOUSE', 'CP')]) %in% 
                                    do.call(paste, small_table[,c('SWH', 'SCP')]),]
```

Comment: Is this a `dplyr` solution (I mean is it efficient at scale)? (@docendodiscimus: yes, but it is trivial to adapt it)

Comment: @user189035 I m not sure about efficiency.